# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'

Tags: python

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
```

on debug mode with PyCharm also after install `pydantic` print

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'

Comment: check `pydantic` installed in right python version which you are using in code ?

Comment: install pydantic==1.6.1 and expected to work ok. another remote machine its work

Comment: Check the interpreter you are using in Pycharm: Settings / Project / Python interpreter. It will list packages installed.

Comment: When this happens, it is often the case that you have two versions of Python on your system, and have installed the package in one of them and are then running your program from the other. - this is especially easy to do if you install the package in your Terminal, but then run your code in your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo pip3 install pydantic
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: open PyCharm preferences and install from Pycharm the package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error while using `pipenv` then you need to install `pydantic` by using `pipenv install pydantic` command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, inside the terminal:

```html
pip3 install pydantic==2.0.3
```

and for me it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).